# Can I partition an iPod (nano, classic, shuffle) for use as a flash drive?

Tags: itunes, bootcamp, ipod, disk-utility, windows

I have made an iPod nano appear as a flash drive by going to iTunes and checking "Enable disk use." However, I am short of a large enough USB key to hold a bootable Windows 8 installer for use by Boot Camp. Because Boot Camp needs to wipe the drive used, can I create a partition in Disk Utility of the iPod and install to that?

Does iPod still work after  creating a new partition for use as a flash disk?

Answer (score 2):

It can be done, but truthfully i would just spend the $15 on an 8gb USB drive.

Anyway, one way of doing it:

- Reboot ipod by pressing menu and center button for 5 secs.
- Before apple logo appears (ie: do it fast) press play/pause and center for 2 secs
- a green checkmark should appear on the screen. It is now in flash disk mode. Connect it to the mac
- Go to disk utility and format it for Fat-32 (or ntfs)
- Use it to install windows.
- after you are done, start up itunes and Restore it.

OBVIOUSLY you will lose everything in the ipod. So after restore copy all the music back.

You might be able to skip the first 3 steps and format it straight away, depending on your h/w version it might work, so check that first.

Comment: Yeah, I have a flash drive. Installing now, but out of curiosity, I wanted to know if this could be done with only a partition of iPod. Thanks, though!

Comment: No problem :) how did the installation go?